# Flex parent is not expanding to children width in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm building a time table. I did this by adding time slots and give them a fixed width in a flex parent. In Chrome, FF and Safari this is working, except IE11.

The problem is that IE 11 is not scaling the flex parent to it's children width.

I made a codepen, to explain, the red part is nog scaling to the full width in IE11 when scrolling.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMjQJq

HTML

```
   <div class="c-time-table__scrollable">
      <div class="c-time-table__wrapper">
        <div class="c-time-table__row">
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
          <div class="c-time-table__item">test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
$component: 'c-time-table';
.#{$component} {

  &__scrollable {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex
  }

  &__wrapper {
    display:flex;
  }

  &__row {
    display:flex;
    background: red;
  }

  &__item {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }

}
```

Comment: Flex isn't fully supported by IE. How about fixing it with a script if you really want to support it?

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 doesn't support CSS flexbox fully. Pls refer https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the -ms-prefixes. The easiest way is compiling your CSS with a preprocessor that supports that, like Koala or Prepros.